# azure pipelines pip requirements taking long

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

currently installing pip requirements in azure pipeline using the following

```
- bash: pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: Install pip package requirements
  workingDirectory: project-requirements
```

Would using bash to install requirements.txt  affect the speed compared to using the python task (CMD) to install requirements.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't expect using `bash` instead of `cmd` to make a substantial difference. To avoid having to wait for installing all packages every pipeline execution, you could extend your current Docker image with all required packages.

```
FROM your-current-docker-image
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```